# Android media player delay in prepare()

Tags: android

I have my code which plays music from the internet. My problem is it has a few delay and causes lag after clicking the button.

I have tried to use the prepareAsync() but no luck. Can anyone please let me know the issue.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause) {
        /** ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause mediaplayer playing */
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(editTextSongURL.getText().toString()); // setup song from http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3 URL to mediaplayer data source
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // you must call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL

        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
        }

        primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I have tried to use the prepareAsync() but no luck"_. That doesn't tell us much. Exactly what did you do and how was the result different from what you had expected?

Comment: @tokis You should almost always be using prepareAsync with MediaPlayer, and it does work.  There are lots of examples on the internet on how to do this.